# How can I determine if my sound card is working or not?

Tags: windows-xp, sound-card

My system (Windows XP) does not have any sound! 
I feel that my sound card is broken, but I'm not sure.
How can I determine whether my sound card is healthy or broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way I can think of is booting from an ubuntu live cd and seeing if it works. That eliminates any software problems you may have under Windows.